# Chainsaw v2 SocketReceiver not working with log4j2 SocketAppender

Tags: sockets, log4j2, apache-chainsaw

I'm trying to use Chainsaw v2 from http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy
I don't want to use zero configuration. Just a simple socketAppender/SocketReceiver combo.

I'm using log4j2 with the following configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" >
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <Socket name="SharathZeroConf" host="localhost" port="4445">
        </Socket>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="SharathZeroConf" />
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
        </Root>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

On ChainSaw, I'm selecting the option "Receive events from network" with port 4445.

However chainsaw doesnt log anything.

I've verified that the appender configuration is correct on log4j side by using the builtin socketserver

```
java -cp ~/.m2/reposiry/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.0.2/log4j-api-2.0.2.jar  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.server.TcpSocketServer 4445
```

So the bug must be on chainsaw side. Any pointers @Scott ?

Comment: After looking at the source code of chainsaw, it looks like chainsaw still uses log4j 1.x and has very limited support for log4j2. In particular, it casts incoming log events from socket as log4j 1.x `org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent` whereas the log4j2 events that are sent are actually `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent` objects

Answer (score 2):

You're right, I got the same issue. I just tried with [LogMX](http://www.logmx.com) instead, and it works like a charm:

[image: LogMX screenshot]

I just had to copy Log4j JARs in LogMX `lib/` directory (i.e. `log4j-api-2.xx.jar` and `log4j-core-2.xx.jar`)

Comment: Wow, awesome, thanks. I'll try it out. I wonder if LogMX explicitly supports log4j2 or its simply working 'by chance'

Comment: I have a weird problem where logmx captures my application logs but doesnt capture spring logs. I can see them in the console though. Also FYI for other people planning to use logmx, the free version limits you to 10,000 logs

Comment: You may want to check your Log4j configuration: the appender used for Spring logs may not be the same as for your application logs (i.e. not a `Socket Appender`), you may want to check your Loggers/Appenders and their `additivity`. Spring logs may also be filtered by package name for Socket Appender through [Log4j `filters`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Filters).